# Can we use GCDAsyncSocket to connect with SSH server?

Tags: ios, unix, ssh, gcdasyncsocket

Earlier i was connecting to unix server with GCDAsyncSocket and everything was fine. Now when I am trying to connect with unix server through SSH with GCDAsyncSocket, I am able to connect with server but negotiation process halt in the middle.

I don't know what is happening around, an error message displayed by GCDAsyncSocket is "Socket closed by remote peer" after sending the Key Exchange Algorithm data.

So i want know whether we can connect to SSH with GCDAsyncSocket or we have to try some other connection library like "NMSSH".

Please help me out of this problem.

Comment: This is pretty vague. Please edit your question to include the source code that isn't working correctly, and any error messages that you're getting. If the server is closing the connection, you should check the server log to see why it's doing that.

Comment: @Kenster ,  Just tell that we can use GCDASyncSocket for SSH or not???